# Delete an element from string pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I have a string pointer array test_array.If it has an empty string i want to go to the end and find an element from the array that isnt empty copy it to the previous empty one and finally delete the end of the array that i just copied.--How will i use delete for this?
--Do i need to use delete or do i have to do delete[] and copy the whole array in a new one?--Does delete only delete the pointer in the array or the string too?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string* test_array = new std::string[5];
    int size = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)//test_array[] 0=a 1=b 2=c 3=d 4=e
    {
        test_array[i] = char('a'+i);
    }

    test_array[1] = "";//test_array[] 0=a 1=empty 2=c 3=d 4=e

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        if (test_array[i].empty())
        {
            while(test_array[size].empty())//Find last position that isnt empty
            {
                delete &test_array[size];//Supposed to delete if empty,probably wrong but the only thing that passed compile

                size--;
            }

            test_array[i] = test_array[size];
            delete &test_array[size];//Supposed to delete if empty

            size--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<"String is: "<<test_array[i]<<'\n';
    }

    std::cout<<"Deleted element: "<<test_array[4]<<'\n';//Shows deleted e
}
```

Comment: Replace `std::string* test_array` with `std::vector <std::string>> test_array`.  The problem is then trivial.

Comment: `Do i need to use delete or do i have to do delete[] and copy the whole array in a new one?` Yes. But in the reversed order: copy and delete[]. `Does delete only delete the pointer in the array or the string too?` You array does not contain pointers. What question is about? Suggest using std::deque if you want to delete strings in the middle.

Comment: @PaulSanders cant use vector

Comment: Your array does not contain `string*` pointers to `string` objects that are created with `new`, only an array of `string` objects that is created with `new[]`, so there is no need to use `delete` on any of the elements at all, only `delete[]` the array itself when the code is finished. When moving data from an element, just `clear()` or `move()` that element to reset it.

Comment: @S.M. so i have to delete[] and make and new one and copy the strings ?Is it the only way because i want to use this on a big array and it will take time

Comment: @Jeepsey.  Why must you explicitly delete the entry?  From the way the assignment has been worded, all you need to do is keep track of the usable "size", and any entry at the end of the 5 element array is just garbage.  It's a matter of simple swaps, and subtracting the end index of the array by 1.  As a matter of fact, a regular old `std::string test_array[5];` would work fine.  In other words, your teacher may be looking to see if you can mimic the STL `std::remove` algorithm function, which doesn't erase anything.

Comment: No, there is no need to `delete[]` the array and `new[]` a new array in this code at all.

Comment: `cant use vector` Very strange. std::string can be used, std::vector can't.

Comment: @S.M. i mean im not allowed

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i want to fill the empty spots of the array so all non empty strings are in a row.And since the end of the array now contains only empty string i want to delete that space

Comment: @Jesepy -- You cannot do a partial delete of something allocated with `new[]`.  Take a step back -- you haven't gotten past the first part of the assignment, and I already mentioned how to accomplish that.   You need to work this out on paper using boxes and arrows indicating the two indices I'm referring to and traversing / swapping.  Once you get past that step, magically the end index should be pointing to the start of the array that is to be "deleted".  That's as far as you can go, as again, you can't do partial `delete[]` on something allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Seriousness aside, you can use `std::basic_string<T>` as a near drop-in replacement for `std::vector<T>`, with all the benefits of automatic memory management, though I doubt your instructor will appreciate this

Comment: @Jesepy -- Basically in a nutshell, you do one big mass "delete" at the end of the processing and starting at the end index after all the swaps.  Since you know that starting at that end index, everything has to go, that makes the delete (whatever that may mean) simple.  Your current code tries to do deletes in the middle of all of this processing, and that makes the code convoluted and difficult to maintain.  That's why I mentioned to not delete anything -- just move things around first to their final spots, and then "delete".

Comment: @Jesepy Another algorithm that your teacher may be thinking of is [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition), which basically does exactly what I mentioned in my comments.  All the non-blank entries go to the left of the partition point, blanks to the right of the partition point.  Then everything on the right of the partition gets "deleted".  This is what you should be trying to mimic.  Try `std::partition(test_array, test_array+5,[&](const std::string& s) { return !s.empty(); });` as an experiment, and see test_array turn into what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `Then everything on the right of the partition gets "deleted"`. `std::partition` doesn't do that. It just re-orders elements. And if your intention is to erase those elements, then `std::remove` would be a more efficient choice. Basically, `std::partition` is same as `std::remove_if`, except it keeps the right hand side elements intact, while `std::remove_if` is not guaranteed to do so - it may leave them in a moved-from state.

Comment: @eerorika I never mentioned that std::partition deletes the elements.   The "deletion" (note the quotes) is whatever the OP considers deleting the elements *after* the partition is done.  I simply stated that std::partition would leave the array in the state where I described -- non empty on the left, empty on the right.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well, "gets deleted" is quite ambiguous. Regardless, that is a case where std::remove is a more efficient choice.

Comment: @eerorika Admittedly, I worded things awkwardly.  I think the OP has no choice but to mimic std::partition first, since I don't know what "delete" would mean to him/her.   Maybe copy up to the partition point to another dynamically allocated array and return that, I don't know -- that's the OP's choice.  Given that the OP can't use vector or a container that actually can have items deleted, don't know what else to say.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's exactly the case where std::remove is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a string pointer array test_array.

test_array is not a "string pointer array". It is a pointer to a string. It points to first element of a dynamic array.

> find an element from the array that isnt empty copy it to the previous empty one and finally delete the end of the array that i just copied.

You cannot "delete" element of an array (unless it is a pointer to a dynamic object / array in which case you're destroying and deallocating the object pointed by the element, and the element remains in the array).

The size of an array cannot change in C++.

> so i have to delete[] and make and new one and copy the strings ?Is it the only way

Firstly, you can move instead of copy.

Secondly, you should move **before** deleting because otherwise there is nothing to move.

Thirdly, there isn't necessarily a need to change the size of the array. Reconsider why you think you need to do that. It can be fine to leave those elements at the end.

Lastly, another way is to use `std::vector`. I recommend this way.

P.S. There is a standard algorithm for what you're doing. It's called `std::remove`.

P.P.S. If you don't need to keep the order of remaining elements the same, then a more efficient algorithm is to simply move the last element over the "removed" one.